# Why does the output keep repeating?

Tags: java, println

I am tryng to make a simple counter that counts the number of times a character is present in a string, but I'm doing something wrong. When i try to print the counter it repeats a number of times.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Uppgift5 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int counter = 0;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What string do you want to search: ");
    String string = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("What letter do you want to count? ");
    String letter = scanner.nextLine();


    for(int i=0; i<string.length(); i++ ) {
        if (string.charAt(i) == letter.charAt(0)){
            counter++; 
        }

        System.out.println("This string has " + counter + " " + letter);

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Place the

```
System.out.println("This string has " + counter + " " + letter);
```

outside of the loop and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Place  `System.out.println("This string has " + counter + " " + letter);` outside the `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

The code should be...

int counter = 0;

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("What string do you want to search: ");
String string = scanner.nextLine();

System.out.println("What letter do you want to count? ");
String letter = scanner.nextLine();


for(int i=0; i<string.length(); i++ ) {
    if (string.charAt(i) == letter.charAt(0)){
        counter++; 
    }

 }
```

System.out.println("This string has " + counter + " " + letter);